# Within Google Apps Script - is it possible to use the Advanced Calendar Service on another account than the current Google Sheet user?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

In my Google Apps Script I'd like to use the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) on Calendars of another Google Account that I also own and have control over.

Just like you would do with the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/).

How is that possible?

Comment: You can directly connect with the api in apps script too

Comment: I searched for an example for this, but didn’t find one. Do you know of any?

Comment: You can  directly use UrlFetchApp to GET/POST requests as you wish.

Comment: If you share the other calendars with the current account then you can use `CalendarApp.getAllCalendars()` to get all of the calendar info.

Comment: If you don't have access to the other calendar, you need to find a way to get an access token. If you do, then simply use that calendar id.

Comment: @Cooper: problem is: correct account changes a lot since many people use that sheet, while calendars to interact with, stays the same.